# Component wise convergence of a sequence of complex harmonic functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, harmonic-functions

It is well known that a complex harmonic function $f$ on a simply connected domain $D$ has a canonical decomposition of the form $$f=g+\bar{h},$$ where $g$ and $h$ are analytic functions on $D.$ In fact, this decomposition is unique if we assume $g(z_0)=0,$ for some $z_0\in D.$

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of non constant complex valued harmonic functions defined on a simply connected domain $D$ such that $\{f_n\}$ converges locally uniformly to some non constant harmonic function $f=g+\bar{h}.$

Assuming $\{f_n\}$ has a canonical decomposition $f_n=g_n + \overline{h_n}.$

Since $\{f_n\}\longrightarrow f$ locally uniformly, can we say that $\{g_n\}\longrightarrow g$ and $\{h_n\}\longrightarrow h$ locally uniformly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is positive. Consider a small disk $D(a,r)$ in the domain of
uniform convergence (the center is at $a$, radius $r$), and expand $f_n(a+te^{i\theta})$ into a harmonic Fourier series:
$$f_k(a+te^{i\theta})=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_{k,n}t^ne^{in\theta},\quad t<r.$$
Then we have $c_{k,n}\to c_n$, as $k\to\infty$ for each $n$, in view of
uniform convergence. Therefore, the analytic parts
$$g_k(a+te^{i\theta})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{k,n}te^{in\theta}$$
converge uniformly on each smaller disk. Then $h_k=\overline{f_k-g_k}$
also converge.

Remark. The Hilbert space $L^2$ of functions on the circle $\partial D(a,r)$ is a direct sum $L^2=H^2_++H^2_-$, where $H^2_+$ and $H^2_-$
are "analytic" and "anti-analytic" parts. So the map $f\mapsto g$
is just a projection onto $H^2_+$. This gives an explicit estimate of norms of $h_n$ in terms of norms of $f$.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks Prof. Eremenko